# Animation of a single face

Tags: animation, faces

Hi I hope someone can help a newbie here. I have a cylinder that I would like to appear to get longer over time. I know how to go into edit mode and select all the vertices of a singular face and move them. But how do I animate it? I know how to animate the whole object but just need the one face of my cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the top face and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object*:

[image]

It has created a *Hook* modifier and an empty, the empty now controls your vertices:

[image]

Back to *Object* mode, select the empty that the hook operation has created, you can move and keyframe it:

[image]

You could also use shapekeys or the *Animall* addon but it's less simple.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: looks like your hook modifier is angry.... :S

Comment: it's a french cylinder, always angry  :/